# Java JNI: possible to manage cache, history, temporary files in IExplorer?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, java-native-interface

Is there a way to use JNI / Java-Com bridge to manage Internet Explorer's cache, history and temporary file options from Java? better a Java library which facilitates this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) (Java Native Access) library.  This library will allow you to call any Win32 .DLL API from pure Java, without writing any JNI (C/C++) code.  It is used by hundreds of projects and works as advertised.  I would use it to wrap the dozen or so API's that you'll need to manage the IE cache, history, etc.  If you Google around for JNA and Win32, you're likely to find lots of examples.